# Third Tab of Bottom Navigation should contain Drawer Menu

Tags: android, material-design, navigation-drawer, bottomnavigationview

I have a requirement to show the Drawer Menu only on the Third Menu of the Bottom Navigation View like this :

[image]

I have achieved this with this block of code :

```
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.thirdFragment), drawerLayout)
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

But Other Screens have a Back Button displayed like this :

[image]

I need to remove the Back Button in other screens. Can it be achieved ?

Comment: ```getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)``` should get rid of the back button.

Comment: @PrinceAli, That action will not solve the issue I am facing

Answer (score 0):

Add the rest of fragments' Ids in the set; I will assume their names:

```
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.thirdFragment,
                                                R.id.firstFragment, 
                                                R.id.secondFragment), drawerLayout)
```